# how do you pass the index from JavaScript when you click to go full screen?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm trying to make a dynamic slider using javascript. how can you get the index of the image to go to the full-screen part so I can move between images with the buttons?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let imgs = [
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/3484061/pexels-photo-3484061.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/5137655/pexels-photo-5137655.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1743165/pexels-photo-1743165.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/3484061/pexels-photo-3484061.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/5137655/pexels-photo-5137655.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1743165/pexels-photo-1743165.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/3484061/pexels-photo-3484061.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/5137655/pexels-photo-5137655.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1743165/pexels-photo-1743165.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
];


let i;

for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    //places thumbnails
    let imgThumb = new Image();
    imgThumb.src = imgs[i];
    let newThumb = document.createElement("div");
    imgThumb.className = "responsive-picture thumbnail";
    imgThumb.id = "thumb" + i;
    document.getElementById("slider1").appendChild(imgThumb);
}

let expandId = document.querySelector("#slider1");
//collects the clicked pictures source
expandId.addEventListener('click', function(c) {
    if (c.target.className == 'responsive-picture thumbnail') {
        let expandedSource = c.target.src;
        console.log('source is', expandedSource.indexOf(imgs));
        showFullScreen(expandedSource);
    }

})

let myIndex = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
console.log(myIndex);

function expand() {
    // expands / removes full screen widget
    let expander = document.getElementById("fullScreen");
    if (expander.classList) {
        expander.classList.toggle("show-hide");
    } else {
        let classes = expander.className.split(" ");
        var i = classes.indexOf("show-hide");

        if (i > 4)
            classes.splice(i, 1);
        else {
            classes.push("show-hide");
            element.className = classes.join(" ");
        }
    }
}


function showFullScreen(expandedSource) {
    expand()
    let exPic = new Image();
    exPic.src = expandedSource
    let newThumb = document.createElement("img");
    let expandCont = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
    exPic.className = "full-screen-pic";
    if (expandCont.hasChildNodes = false) {
        expandCont.appendChild(exPic);
        return expandedSource;
    } else {
        expandCont.replaceChild(exPic, expandCont.childNodes[0]);
        return expandedSource;
    }

}
/* 
    function slideshow() {
        let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("responsive-picture thumbnail");
        for (s in slides) {
            console.log()

        }
    }

    function changeFsSlide(n) {
        slideshow();
        console.log('go backwards yet??')
    } */


//button listners
let fsExit = document.querySelector("#sl-exit");
fsExit.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    expand()
})

let fsPrev = document.querySelector("#fs-prev");
fsPrev.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // i--;
    console.log(i);
})

let fsNext = document.querySelector("#fs-next");
fsNext.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (i >= imgs.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    i++;
    console.log(i);
})
```

I've tried several different ways to get the slider to work from putting functions inside the buttons, trying to pull an index and then increment. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Code look overkill to me. You should have attached an Event to each Element when you assigned the image `src`s.

Comment: Alright. did that and got rid of that query selector for slider1. Still need a way to cycle through the pictures when you click the buttons